# Delete rows conditionally

Tags: sql

I have a dataset with over 100,000 rows, over 100 columns and where some values are `NULL`. Now I want to remove all the rows which contain `NULL` values.

Can anybody suggest the sql command for it?

Comment: Please post the code you have written so far. People generally do not like to just write your code for you. As it is, this is a work description, not a question.

Answer (score 16):

With the little information you've provided:

```
DELETE FROM table WHERE colA IS NULL OR colB is NULL
```

Add further conditions for each column that you want to check.

Change `OR` to `AND` if you only want to delete rows where all of the columns are NULL.

It's fairly easy to generate the SQL for this using a query on `user_tab_columns` if you don't want to type it out by hand.

Answer (score 0):

use a scripting language like PHP to retreive all column names and then construct your SQL query.
Using pure SQL could get tricky.

Comment: DB2, Oracle, SQL Server, PostgreSQL, MySQL, Interbase, Paradox, MS Access and even dBase have easier ways to get all column names from a table, without having to write any kind of script for that.

Comment: Thanks Dave,ITroubs & rsenna! I just want to know if we there's a posibility to create vba like script for deleting rows within SQL.

Comment: I don't knoow VBA but if it is possible in PHP then it should be possible in VBA too.